# mod_rewrite select everything

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with URL rewriting. This is the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ file.php?name=test&a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

The rule work's fine on a link like this:

```
test-11-abc.html
```

But I have a problem if the third variable have a dash like:

```
test-11-ab-c.html
```

The rewrite doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*)\.html$ file.php?name=test&a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

You need to make the first 2 matches non-greedy, because they're gobbling up the first `-`.